# Mustache templates, list of options and formatting

Tags: mustache, openapi-generator

I'm using mustache templates to generate [Jetbrains HTTP Client](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/exploring-http-syntax.html) files from [OpenAPI specifications](https://www.openapis.org/). (Though you don't need any of that context, my question is about mustache templates.)

In short, I can have zero, one or many security options and whatever the result I'd like each of the results to neatly be on a new line.

How to ensure that, if the options are false, the line breaks are ignored by the templating?

So far I haven't managed to format things as desired.

For example, for a query where `isBasicBasic` is true, `isBasicBearer` is false and `isApiKey` is true, using the following template:

```
{{httpMethod}} {{basePath}}{{#lambda.doubleMustache}}{{path}}{{/lambda.doubleMustache}}
{{#authMethods}}{{#isBasicBasic}}Authorization: Basic username password{{/isBasicBasic}}
{{#isBasicBearer}}Authorization: Bearer token{{/isBasicBearer}}
{{#isApiKey}}{{keyParamName}} apiKey{{/isApiKey}}{{/authMethods}}
{{#consumes}}Content-Type: {{{mediaType}}}
{{/consumes}}
```

The result I get at the moment is:

```
## BasicApi

### Get User
## Get User Info by User ID
# @name getUsersUserId
GET http://localhost:5001/v1/users/{{userId}}
Authorization: Basic username password



X-API-Key apiKey
```

while the desired result is:

```
## BasicApi

### Get User
## Get User Info by User ID
# @name getUsersUserId
GET http://localhost:5001/v1/users/{{userId}}
Authorization: Basic username password
X-API-Key apiKey
```

Putting everything on one line will remove the additional line breaks, but that is not helpful:

```
{{httpMethod}} {{basePath}}{{#lambda.doubleMustache}}{{path}}{{/lambda.doubleMustache}}
{{#authMethods}}{{#isBasicBasic}}Authorization: Basic username password{{/isBasicBasic}}{{#isBasicBearer}}Authorization: Bearer token{{/isBasicBearer}}{{#isApiKey}}{{keyParamName}} apiKey{{/isApiKey}}{{/authMethods}}
{{#consumes}}Content-Type: {{{mediaType}}}
```

returns:

```
### Get User
## Get User Info by User ID
# @name getUsersUserId
GET http://localhost:5001/v1/users/{{userId}}
Authorization: Basic username passwordX-API-Key apiKey
```

I am not generating HTML, meaning that I don't think I can insert manual line breaks like `<br>`. I tried manually inserting carriage returns, but they just render in text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mustache has the concept of *standalone tags*. If a section or end section tag appears on a line by itself with nothing but whitespace, it is guaranteed not to leave an empty line in the output. Hence, you can write this instead:

```
{{httpMethod}} {{basePath}}{{#lambda.doubleMustache}}{{path}}{{/lambda.doubleMustache}}
{{#authMethods}}
    {{#isBasicBasic}}
Authorization: Basic username password
    {{/isBasicBasic}}
    {{#isBasicBearer}}
Authorization: Bearer token
    {{/isBasicBearer}}
    {{#isApiKey}}
{{keyParamName}} apiKey
    {{/isApiKey}}
{{/authMethods}}
{{#consumes}}
Content-Type: {{{mediaType}}}
{{/consumes}}
```

You can try it out by copy-pasting the following savestate into the load/store box in the [playground](https://jgonggrijp.gitlab.io/wontache/playground.html) (see the second template):

```
{"data":{"text":"{\n    httpMethod: 'GET',\n    basePath: 'http://localhost:5001/v1/',\n    path: 'users/{{userId}}',\n    lambda: {\n        doubleMustache(content) {\n            return true;\n        },\n    },\n    authMethods: [{\n        isBasicBasic: true,\n    }, {\n        isApiKey: true,\n        keyParamName: 'X-API-Key',\n    }],\n}"},"templates":[{"name":"original-solution","text":"{{httpMethod}} {{basePath}}{{#lambda.doubleMustache}}{{path}}{{/lambda.doubleMustache}}\n{{#authMethods}}{{#isBasicBasic}}Authorization: Basic username password\n{{/isBasicBasic}}{{#isBasicBearer}}Authorization: Bearer token\n{{/isBasicBearer}}{{#isApiKey}}{{keyParamName}} apiKey\n{{/isApiKey}}{{/authMethods}}\n{{#consumes}}Content-Type: {{{mediaType}}}{{/consumes}}"},{"text":"{{httpMethod}} {{basePath}}{{#lambda.doubleMustache}}{{path}}{{/lambda.doubleMustache}}\n{{#authMethods}}\n    {{#isBasicBasic}}\nAuthorization: Basic username password\n    {{/isBasicBasic}}\n    {{#isBasicBearer}}\nAuthorization: Bearer token\n    {{/isBasicBearer}}\n    {{#isApiKey}}\n{{keyParamName}} apiKey\n    {{/isApiKey}}\n{{/authMethods}}\n{{#consumes}}\nContent-Type: {{{mediaType}}}\n{{/consumes}}","name":"standalone-solution"}]}
```

Comment: TIL about the playground, nice!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I realized that I wasn't following the mustach guidelines, trying to have a nice looking template file instead.

To have line breaks printed only in the case they are present, the solution is to **put those liner breaks inside the conditional template**.

So writing this :

```
{{httpMethod}} {{basePath}}{{#lambda.doubleMustache}}{{path}}{{/lambda.doubleMustache}}
{{#authMethods}}{{#isBasicBasic}}Authorization: Basic username password
{{/isBasicBasic}}{{#isBasicBearer}}Authorization: Bearer token
{{/isBasicBearer}}{{#isApiKey}}{{keyParamName}} apiKey
{{/isApiKey}}{{/authMethods}}
{{#consumes}}Content-Type: {{{mediaType}}}
```

renders as desired :

```
### Get User
## Get User Info by User ID
# @name getUsersUserId
GET http://localhost:5001/v1/users/{{userId}}
Authorization: Basic username password
X-API-Key apiKey
```

Comment: A cleaner way is to use standalone tags. See my answer.